# Guess the closed form on the following sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

any help would be appreciated, have no idea where to start

$u_1 = 2/3$ and $u_{k+1}$ such that:

$$u_k + \frac{1}{(k+2)(k+3)}$$ for all, k are natural numbers

guess a general formula (i.e the closed form) of the sequence

Comment: Do you mean $u_{k+1}=u_k+\frac{1}{(k+2)(k+3)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u_{k+1}=u_k+\dfrac{1}{(k+2)(k+3)}$, then we have the following sequence
$$\left\{\dfrac23,\dfrac23+\dfrac{1}{12},\dfrac23+\dfrac{1}{12}+\dfrac{1}{20},\dfrac23+\dfrac{1}{12}+\dfrac{1}{20}+\dfrac{1}{30},\dots\right\}=\left\{\dfrac23,\dfrac34,\dfrac45,\dfrac56,\dots\right\}$$
Then the general formula for $k\in\mathbb N$ would be 
$$\left\{\dfrac{k+1}{k+2}\right\}_{k=1}^\infty$$

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
\color{#c00000}{u_{k + 1}}&=u_{k} + {1 \over \pars{k + 2}\pars{k + 3}}
=\color{#c00000}{u_{k} + {1 \over k + 2} - {1 \over k + 3}}
\\[3mm]&=\pars{u_{k - 1} + {1 \over k + 1} - {1 \over k + 2}} + {1 \over k + 2}
- {1 \over k + 3} = \color{#c00000}{u_{k - 1} + {1 \over k + 1} - {1 \over k + 3}}
\\[3mm]&=\pars{u_{k - 2} + {1 \over k} - {1 \over k + 1}} + {1 \over k + 1}
- {1 \over k + 3}= \color{#c00000}{u_{k - 2} + {1 \over k} - {1 \over k + 3}}=\cdots
\\[3mm]&=
\color{#c00000}{\overbrace{u_{1}}^{\ds{{2 \over 3}}} + {1 \over 3} - {1 \over k + 3}}
={k + 2 \over k + 3} 
\end{align}

> $$\color{#00f}{\large%
> u_{k} = {k + 1 \over k + 2}\,,\qquad k \geq 1}
> $$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** So $u_1=\frac{2}{3}$ and $u_2=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{(3)(4)}$ and $u_3=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{(3)(4)}+\frac{1}{(4)(5)}$ and so on.

Note that $\frac{1}{(3)(4)}=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{(4)(5)}=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}$.

Do a couple more terms and notice the beautiful cancellations (telescoping). In general $\frac{1}{(k+2)(k+3)}=\frac{1}{k+2}-\frac{1}{k+3}$.